# Calculate $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_0^t \ln(e^x+x^2)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I need to calculate this:
$$ \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_0^t \ln(e^x+x^2)\,dx$$

Here's what I've done (in short):
Let $f(x)=\ln(e^x+x^2)$, f is continue in $[0, \infty)$, hence for each $t>0$, there is a number $c_t$ such that $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(x)\,dx=f(c_t)$.
When $t\to\infty, c_t\to\infty$, so:

$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \ln(e^x+x^2)\,dx= \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t}f(c_t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{f(c_t)}{t}=(L'Hospital)\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{(\ln(e^x+x^2))'}{(t)'}=.....=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{e^c_t}{e^c_t}=..=1$

Everyone in my class saying the answer is $1/2$, but I can't find my mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To apply l'Hopital you'd need to somehow find $\frac{d f(c_t)}{dt}$

Comment: @ChristianF I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you substitute $f(c_t)$ back in to your limit you forgot the extra $\frac{1}{t}$ term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ G(t)= \int_0^t\ln(e^x+x^2)dx$

$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{G(t)}{t^2}  = \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{f(t)}{2t} (L'Hospital)$

the derivative of $t^2$ is $2t$

Comment: In order to apply L'Hospital rule you need to show that both $G(t)$ and $t^2$ goes to infinity, but why $G(t)\to\infty$?

Comment: @Avishay28: in order to apply L'Hospital's Rule it is sufficient to show that denominator tends to $\infty$ in absolute value without worrying about numerator.

Comment: @Avishay28 $ln(e^x +x^2)$ goes to infinity as $x$ increases so does its integral

Answer (score 4):

Loosely speaking, one expects the $x^2$ perturbation to be negligible for $t\to+\infty$, and from
$$ \frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}\log(e^x+x^2)\,dx \stackrel{?}{\approx}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}\log(e^x)\,dx = \frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}x\,dx = \frac{1}{2} $$
$\frac{1}{2}$ is definitely the most reasonable answer. One just needs to turn the $\stackrel{?}{\approx}$ above into a rigorous thing,
i.e. to prove that 
$$ \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}\log(1+x^2 e^{-x})\,dx = 0. $$
On the other hand $x^2 e^{-x}$ is a non-negative and bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence $\int_{0}^{t}\log(1+x^2 e^{-x})\,dx=O(t)$ and the previous identity is trivial. We do not even need derivatives.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem from the beginning! I was thinking $t\to 0$!

Answer (score 3):

Let's use L'Hospital rule:

$$ \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_0^t \ln(e^x+x^2)\,dx =  \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{2t} \ln(e^t+t^2) ={1\over 2}\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{e^t+2t}{e^t+t^2} ={1\over 2}$$

Comment: Yes this is the solution (good edit :p) I do not know why the OP uses the $f(c_t)$ trick

Comment: I think you should mention Lhopital's rule when you are using it.

Comment: There was no need to apply L'Hospital's Rule twice. Just write $\log(e^t+t^2)=t+\log(1+t^2e^{-t})$ ans show the limit to be $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

By the monotonicity of the $\log$:
$$0\le x\le t\implies x\le\log(e^x + x^2)\le\log(e^x + t^2) = x + \log(1 + t^2e^{-x})\le x + \log(1 + t^2).$$
Integrating:
$$\frac{t^2}2\le\int_0^t\log(e^x + x^2)\,dx\le\frac{t^2}{2} + t\log(1 + t^2).$$
Dividing by $t^2$ and squeezing, we conclude
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t\log(e^x + x^2)\,dx = \frac12.$$